# Value of type 'Post' has no member 'adjustLikes' (Swift compiler error)

Tags: swift, firebase

I am receiving an error message of the following:

> Value of type 'Post' has no member 'adjustLikes'

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func liked(_ sender: Any) {
    let likeRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUser!).child("likes").child(post.postKey)
    likeRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  { (snapshot) in
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
            self.post.adjustLikes(addlike: true)
            likeRef.setValue(true)
        } else {
            self.post.adjustLikes(addlike: false)
            likeRef.removeValue()
```

Comment: show us your Post class

Comment: Things I'd try: 1. changing `self.post.adjustLikes(` to `self.post().adjustLikes(` 2. deleting `self` 3. sharing your post class with us 4. possibly capitalizing post 5. following suggestions from 1 and 2 and/or 3 simultaneously